# Does StackExchange have Social Responsibility Projects?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I was just wondering, is there a project like this?

Maybe there is but I didn't hear about it.

[image]

What do you think about that?

Comment: For those of us not in the know of the terminology, it wouldn't hurt to explain what a Social Responsibility Project is, without requiring us to seek external reference material ourselves.

Comment: What relevance does the image have?

Comment: @ChrisF It makes an unclear, short question appear to have more importance and weight than is warranted.

Comment: @ChrisF: On SE, it reminds me of [Ubuntu's logo](http://askubuntu.com/). I'm pretty sure that's *not* what the OP had in mind, though.

Comment: The guy to the left looks distinctly Vulcan to me. It's an off-worlder conspiracy! Out with off-worlders!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_responsibility):

> Social responsibility is an ethical ideology or theory that an entity, be it an organization or individual, has an obligation to act to benefit society at large.

Stack Exchange Inc (SEI), in and of itself, can be considered a social responsibility project.  The site not only provides a place for people to get answers, it does so without charge, and even goes so far as to give away, via creative commons, the data that is collected from its users.

The mechanisms SEI uses to encourage users to contribute their time and effort for free end up encouraging users to provide a wealth of information to the world.

In a sense, Stack Exchange provides a place for people to fulfill their individual social responsibility, and does so in a manner that people want to contribute to this global knowledge store.

So not only does Stack Exchange fulfill its social responsibility, it gets individuals to fulfill theirs.

Comment: Also: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/stack-overflow-gives-back/ http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-gives-back-2010/

Comment: @balpha that would be worth an answer  on its own IMO

Answer (score 8):

As pointed out by @balpha in the comments, they have made donations to several charity and Open Source projects in the past.

- [Stack Overflow Gives Back 2009](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/stack-overflow-gives-back/)
- [Stack Overflow Gives Back 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-gives-back-2010/)

they also sponsor the [Bad Code offsets](http://codeoffsets.com/Sponsors.aspx) project  if you count that as a "social responsibility project".

Comment: "Gives Back" implies they are taking away something in the first place. Makes me puke a little in my mouf.

Comment: @Won Oh, they are taking something away alright.  **Productive working hours**  */me sobs silently*